# Can I Use Boost Message Queues for Thread Communication

Tags: multithreading, boost, message-queue

I am spawning multiple worker threads from a main thread. Can I create message_queue for each thread from the main thread and send messages from the main thread. Am I asking this because message queues are meant for interprocess communication.

Do I need to consider anything specific regarding this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by [Boost Message Queue not based on POSIX message queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408059/boost-message-queue-not-based-on-posix-message-queue-impossible-to-select2) (and mentioned in the documentation). If you are talking about threads you have the same address space and do not need inter-process capabilities.

I would advice to use a STL container of your choice within my wrapper class (has-a relationship) and surround the setter/getter with synchronization elements (mutable exclusion/mutex), as mentioned by [How do I create synchronization mechanisms in managed shared memory segments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321530/how-do-i-create-synchronization-mechanisms-in-managed-shared-memory-segments) The missing serialization of objects is a performance advantage over inter-process communication -- copy data chunks between processes boundaries. On the other hand you can use all the neat features, e.g. `shared_ptr`.